# Prove That C Is Invertible A=CB

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let there $A,B,C\in M_n(\mathbb{F)}$ such that $A=CB$.

Prove: If $Null(A)=Null(B)$ than $C$ is Invertible.

Proof: $Null(B)\subseteq Null(CB)=Null(A)=Null(B)\rightarrow Null(C)=\{0\} $
by rank-nullity theorem  $n=rank(C)+null(C)\rightarrow n=Rank(C)$
therefore the rank of $C$ is full and it is invertible.

is this right? is there a shorter way?

Comment: What if $A=B=C=0$?

Comment: @AMPerrine You are right, so this can not be proved?

Comment: Not unless there is some additional information that has been left out.

Comment: @AMPerrine nope thats all, leaving out that option $A=B=C=0$ , let say $B\neq C$ is the proof is right?

Comment: If $E$ is the matrix with $1$ in the upper left-hand corner and $0$ elsewhere, then $A=6E$, $B=3E$, and $C=2E$ is a counterexample where all three matrices are different.

Comment: I guess that the statement should be: if $A, B\in M_n{\mathbb F}$ are such that $Null(A)=Null(B)$, then there exists an invertible $C\in M_n{\mathbb F}$ such that $A=CB$.

Comment: @JankoBracic I double checked, it is as I wrote $A,B,C\in M_n\mathbb{F}$